# [noun]+of+[noun] vs. [noun]+[noun]

Tags: grammar, prepositions, adjectives, nouns, of-genitive

What's the difference between these two structures? For example, take a look at this sentence: *"**The flow of fuel** in an old machine like mine is regulated by a carburetor, which draws fuel into the cylinder by passing the flow of air -- whose speed is regulated by a butterfly valve -- across a narrow opening called a "jet"."*
Would it be different if it said "**The fuel flow**" instead? Why?

Comment: No, it wouldn't be different in meaning, only in structure. That's a frequent use of noun compounds, though _of_ isn't the only preposition that can be deleted.

Comment: @JohnLawler Do you know where can I read more about it or what is the grammatical term for that? Aren't there cases where one is preferred over the other? Finally, could you give some examples using different prepositions, I thought only "of" could replace an [adj]+[noun].  Thanks for you answer.

Comment: "Noun compound", also known as "compound noun", is the technical term. And there isn't any "one" or "the other" -- it's not a binary category. There are dozens of types, depending on the meaning. And it's not "[adj]+[noun]", so you're starting off with bad information.